# How to check if a range from Min to Max overlaps with the list of existing ranges in python

Tags: python, django, list, set, django-orm

Suppose I have a model called Voucher with the following existing entries:

```
      ==MinPrice==      ==MaxPrice==
        10                 100
        101                200
        201                500
```

When inserting new records in the Voucher table I want to check the new data records MinPrice and MaxPrice range should not overlap with existing records. In that case all the below entries should be considered as invalid because they are overlapping with the ranges of existing records.

```
       50           800   Invalid
       50           80    Invalid
       150          199   Invalid
       200          300   Invalid
```

and the below entries should be valid:

```
       501           550  Valid
       0             9    Valid
```

I have tried the below ORM query to check if there are any records which overlaps with new entries.

```
query = Q(MinPrice__gte=minimum_price) & Q(MaxPrice__lte=maximum_price)
vouchers = Voucher.objects.filter(query)
if not vouchers:
    #save the new record
```

Comment: If the new minimum or maximum are within any of the existing ranges, then it overlaps.  If not, then not.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried it like this `SELECT min_age, max_age FROM age_table WHERE min_age >= minage or max_age >= maxage` but it does not work as expected.

Comment: Why did you tag python, django? You want things in sql?

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this an SQL question or a Python question?

Comment: Yea I am doing it in Django, I think I have make it complicated, let me update the question and make it easy.

Comment: I have updated the my question, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would be easier to first see when vouchers do *not* overlap, and then invert the condition.

So, when is there no overlap? Either:

- The new voucher is completely smaller than the existing one (e.g. `Voucher(50, 100)` vs `Voucher(101, 200)`); or
- The new voucher is completely larger than the existing one (e.g. `Voucher(250, 300)` vs `Voucher(101, 200)`).

The next insight is that these conditions can each be simplified to:

- `old_voucher.MinPrice > maximum_price`; or
- `old_voucher.MaxPrice < minimum_price`.

Then we invert the whole condition, which in the Django Query API is done with `~`:

```
query = ~(Q(MinPrice__gt=maximum_price) | Q(MaxPrice__lt=minimum_price))
```

We can eliminate the `~` by invoking the relevant [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
query = ~Q(MinPrice__gt=maximum_price) & ~Q(MaxPrice__lt=minimum_price)
```

... and then using the rules of negating comparisons to simplify that to:

```
query = Q(MinPrice__lte=maximum_price) & Q(MaxPrice__gte=minimum_price)
```

This should work, but I can't test it for you. If this doesn't work for you, please consider editing your question so it contains a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).